# Scope changes inside promise "then" methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, promise, q

I've written the following program that processes all files in a directory every N milliseconds:

```
fs = require "fs"
Q = require "q"

class FileProcessor
  constructor: (options) ->
    @dir = options.dir
    @delay = options.delay

  processFiles: ->
    Q.nfcall fs.readdir, @dir
    .then (files) -> Q.all files.map (file) -> @processFile file # <-- Error!
    .then -> Q.delay @delay
    .then -> @processFiles()
    .done()

  processFile: (file) ->
    deferred = Q.defer()

    # Does some stuff.

    return deferred.promise

fp = new FileProcessor(dir: "photos", delay: 1000)
fp.processFiles()
```

On line 11 I get this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It seems `@processFile` is not in scope. How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CoffeeScript contains "fat arrows" that preserve lexical context. (Just like JavaScript in ES6).

Whenever you want to preserve the `this` value, use `=>` instead of `->`:

```
@x = 5
someFnCall someArg
.then (result) => console.log @x  # this will work
```

(Note that in highly concurrent and intensive work, this can be slow - you might want to use a promise library that supports context instead like Bluebird)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know coffeescript so I'll answer in normal JS:

Your `processFiles` function translates to:

```
FileProcessor.prototype.processFiles = function() {
    return Q.nfcall(fs.readdir, this.dir).then(function(files) {
      return Q.all(files.map(this.processFile));
    }).then(function() {
      return Q.delay(this.delay);
    }).then(this.processFiles).done();
  };
```

You can clearly see that the `this.processFile` is being called inside an anonimous function passed to the then. Which means that the `this` scope is not an instance of your FileProcessor.

Comment: `this.processFile` in the `Q.all` line will throw an error since `this` is set to the global context in non strict mode and to undefined otherwise per the Promises/A+ specification.

Comment: Similarly, the `Q.delay(this.delay)` in the second `.then` will err, the last `this.processFiles` will work, though without a `this` value set.